# What are the names of these tools?

Tags: tools

I wonder what names are for all these tools in the picture? How are they used and what are they used for?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is a driver set.  It includes a handle (the green item), several bits (lower left) and several sockets (upper left).  The long items in the lower middle is an extender. One of the items in the bit tray is an adapter to allow the handle to accomodate the sockets.

The bits make it a multi purpose screwdriver. The sockets make it a nut driver.

Comment: Thanks! (1) Is the green handle used with only bits, not the sockets? (2) Is that long item in the lower middle a handle used with sockets only, not bits? (3) How does that "ADP" bit "allow the handle to accomodate the sockets"? Thanks!

Comment: The green handle is used with ALL of the other pieces. To use the sockets, you put the adapater (ADP) in the handle. This converts the hex (6 sided) handle to square. You then put the sockets on the adapter.  If you need a longer reach, you put the female end of the extender on the adapter and the socket on the male end of the extender. The upper extender is to give additina reach for the bits. It should be hex on bothe the female and male end. The male end goes into the handle and the female end receives the bits.